# Call onClick from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have created a Live Search that displays results in a table row. Row has `onClick` function that executes a process of selecting result. `OnClick` function works fine by mouse click but I want user can select it by up/down arrow key and Enter too. Now I want function set in `onClick` is called from other JavaScript function. Any help please......

Comment: do you use jQuery ? if so you could venture into [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Answer (score 2):

```
myElement.onclick = function() {
    // called when myElement is clicked
}
```

or just

```
myElement.click(); // clicks the element
```

And use an onkeydown event to call it, and just check for characters before the click();

```
myField.onkeydown = function() {
    myElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$('tr').live({
      click:  function(e)
    {       
        //your code here;
    },
      keyup: function(e)
        {
              // and here;
        }
   })
```

it requires jQuery